# When an array is subject to Garbage Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

A few years ago I read the book the CLR via C# and the other day I got asked whether an array and still got a bit puzzled, the question was to figure out when the array in the method below is available to garbage collection:

```
public static double ThingRatio()
{
    var input = new [] { 1, 1, 2 ,3, 5 ,8 };
    var count = input.Length;
    // Let's suppose that the line below is the last use of the array input
    var thingCount = CountThings(input);
    input = null;
    return (double)thingCount / count;
}
```

According to the answer given here: [When is an object subject to garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993209/when-is-an-object-subject-to-garbage-collection) which states:

> They will both become eligible for collection as soon as they are not
>   needed anymore. This means that under some circumstances, objects can
>   be collected even before the end of the scope in which they were
>   defined. On the other hand, the actual collection might also happen
>   much later.

I would tend to say that starting after line 6 (i.e. `input = null;`) the array becomes subject to GC but I am not that sure... (I mean the array is supposedly surely no longer needed after the assignment, but also struggling that it's after the `CountThings` call but at the same time the array is "needed" for the null assignment).

Comment: So... you're just having doubts about the accepted answer in that question you linked?

Comment: @Broots Waymb I have a doubt between after the CountThings call and the null assignment

Comment: After the CountThings call the value is still referenced - unless the compiler picks it up and refactors it somehow, I'd say that GC won't touch that value before null assignment.

Comment: i would say its subject to GC before the line of `input = null` if the compiler is smart enough. If you are wondering about whether you need to assign it to null to help GC then the answer is no. absolutely not necessary

Comment: @Steve how can we find this out? I am thinking maybe checking the IL code maybe if the null is not "translated" then that means that this assignment is not needed to make it subject to garbage collection. I am not sure "how dumb" the compiler is.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret if you just remove the `input = null;` line then input is subject to GC right after `CountThings(input);` without a doubt. Even the dumbest compiler wouldnt fail this. Unless you are trying to make a compiler and micro optimize in every bit possible, i wouldnt even worry about it.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb purely for the sake of better understanding the GC, I am just curious and try to understand things in deep.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret All of those things are stated *right from the answer you quoted*, which itself links to sources of additional information.

Comment: @Servy I didn't find an answer about a possible optimization of the GC (due to the null assignment) in those links.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret It's literally in the part of the answer that you quoted.  It specifically says that objects can be collected as soon as they are no longer needed, and that may be even before the end of methods with variables referencing them.

Comment: @Servy kinda disagree, to me "This means that under some circumstances, objects can be collected even before the end of the scope in which they were defined." it's blurry, it does not say explicitly that there might be an optimization from the compiler or at a later point.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret It doesn't use the word "optimization", it just states what the GC is allowed to do.  It's allowed to clean up any objects which will never be used again.  It's entirely up to the implementation to determine when to do so, at any time after that point.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret the answer is different in Debug and Release mode. In Debug JIT extends "local variable" root to its lexical scope - to make debugging easier. In Release JIT uses Eager Root Collection to reduce "local variable" root existence to the possible minimum. In your case, JIT would remember `input` as unreachable after `CountThings` call (or even earlier if it would be inlined). Null assignment is not needed (and is in fact ignored, as you've noticed). And no - those are implementation details and currently there is no way to look at those JIT-generated root ranges (called GCInfo BTW).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember objects and variables are not the same thing. A *variable* has a scope to particular method or type, but the object it refers to or used to refer to has no such concept; it's just a blob of memory. If the GC runs after `input = null;` but before the end of the method, the array is just one more orphaned object. It's not **reachable**, and therefore eligible for collection.

And "reachable" (rather then "needed" ) is the key word here. The array object is no longer needed after this line:  `var thingCount = CountThings(input);`. However, it's still reachable, and so could not be collected at that point...

We also need to remember it isn't collected right away. It's only *eligible* to be collected. As a practical matter, I've found the .Net runtime doesn't tend to invoke the GC in the middle of a user method unless it really has to. *Generally speaking, it is not needed or helpful to set a variable to `null` early,* and in some rare cases can even be harmful.

Finally, I'll add that the code we read and write is not the same code actually used by the machine. Remember, there is also a compile step to translate all this to IL, and later a JIT process to create the final machine code that really runs. Even concept of one line following next is already an abstraction away from what actually happens. One line may expand to be several lines of actual IL, or in some cases even be re-written to involve all new compiler-generated types as with closures or iterator blocks. So everything here is really only referring to the simple case.

Comment: true I think even at the IL stage (I played with  https://sharplab.io) the null assignment already disappeared

Answer (score 4):

> GC Myth: setting an object's reference to null will force the GC to collect it right away.
>   GC Truth: setting an object's reference to null will sometimes allow the GC to collect it sooner.

Taking part of the blogpost I'm referencing below and applying it to your question, the answer is as follows:

The JIT is usually smart enough to realize that `input = null` can be optimized away. That leaves `CountThings(input)` as the last reference to the object. So after that call, the `input` is no longer used and is removed as a GC Root. That leaves the Object in memory orphaned (no references pointing to it), making it eligible for collection. When the GC actually goes about collecting it, is another matter.

More information to be found at [To Null or Not to Null](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clyon/2004/12/01/to-null-or-not-to-null/)

Answer (score 3):

No object can be garbage-collected while it is recognized as existing.  An object will exist in .NET for as along as any reference to it exists or it has a registered finalizer, and will cease to exist once neither condition applies.  References in objects will exist as long as the objects themselves exist, and references in automatic variables will exist as long as there is any means via which they will be observed.  If the garbage collector detects that the only references to an object with no registered finalizer are held in weak references, those references will be destroyed, causing the object to cease to exist.  If the garbage collector detects that the only references to an object with a registered finalizer are held in weak references, any weak references whose "track resurrection" property is false, a reference to the object will be placed in a strongly-rooted list of objects needing "immediate" finalization, and the finalizer will be unregistered (thus allowing it to cease to exist if and when the finalizer reaches a point in execution where no reference to the object could ever be observed).

Note that some sources confuse the triggering of an object's finalizer with garbage-collection, but an object whose finalizer is triggered is guaranteed to continue to exist for at least as long as that finalizer takes to execute, and may continue to exist indefinitely if any references to it exist when the finalizer finishes execution.

In your example, there are three scenarios that could apply, depending upon what `CountThings` does with the passed-in reference:

1. If `CountThings` does not store a copy of the reference anywhere, or any copies of references that it does store get overwritten before `input` gets overwritten, then it will cease to exist as soon as `input` gets overwritten or ceases to exist [automatic-duration variables may cease to exist any time a compiler determines that their value will no longer be observed].
2. If `CountThings` stores a copy of the reference somewhere that continues to exist after it returns, and the last extant reference is held by something other than a weak reference, then the object will cease to exist as soon as the last reference is destroyed.
3. If the last existing reference the array ends up being held in a weak reference, the array will continue to exist until the first GC cycle where that is the case, whereupon the weak reference will be cleared, causing the array to cease to exist.  Note that the lack of non-weak references to the array will only be relevant when a GC cycle occurs.  It is possible (and not particularly uncommon) for a program to store a copy of a reference into a `WeakReference`, `ConditionalWeakTable`, or other object holding some form of weak reference, destroy all other copies, and then read out the weak reference to produce a non-weak copy of the reference before the next GC cycle.  If that occurs, the system will neither know nor care that there was a time when non non-weak copies of the reference existed.  If the GC cycle occurs before the reference gets read out, however, then code which later examines the weak reference will find it blank.

A key observation is that while finalizers and weak references complicate things slightly, the only way in which the GC destroys objects is by invalidating weak forms of references.  As far as the GC is concerned, the only kinds of storage that exist when the system isn't actually performing a GC cycle are those used by objects that exist, those used for .NET's internal purposes, and regions of storage that are available to satisfy future allocations.  If an object is created, the storage it occupied will cease to be a region of storage available for future allocations.  If the object later ceases to exist, the *storage* that had contained the object will also cease to exist in any form the GC knows about until the next GC cycle.  The next GC cycle won't destroy the object (which had already ceased to exist), but will instead add the storage which had contained it back to its list of areas that are available to add future allocations (causing that storage to exist again).